# Remove Price from email invoice?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, invoice, email-templates

**Does anyone know how to remove the price from the email invoice template?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look in this folder:

```
design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\template\email\order
```

maybe files `invoice/items.phtml` or `items/invoice/default.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing the .phtml file you should define a new email template using System -> Transactional Emails -> Add New Template.

Amongst other advantages this allows you to edit the template HTML directly in the admin system. As a starting point you can load the default "New Invoice" template and then alter the content as you wish. Remember to give the template a meaningful name.

Now, to enable this template for invoice emails go to System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails and set your new template as the Invoice Email Template.

Comment: yes I did that already, but in the template file there is nothing to edit in regards to the customer order info and pricing.  The template file calls for an outside variable which I do not know the location of. THE CODE:



<tr class="order-information">
        <td>
            {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                </tr>